# "Erro" ao carregar data

Tags: c#, data, datepicker

Tenho uma tela cujo um determinado campo "Data de Referência" recebe a próxima data disponível de um arquivo, seguindo as datas que estão no banco de dados.

Do lado do campo tenho um ícone "calendar" que ao ser acionado deveria carregar o calendário.

Bom, não sei o que está acontecendo, ele não retorna a próxima data e não carrega o calendário, não estou visualizando erros no código.

"Data de Referência" > txtDataArchive

Verificação da Periodicidade e data = "VerificaDataDisponivel(ds)"

Ação do calendário > "dpbDataArchive"

```
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DATELASTARCHIVE"] != DBNull.Value && ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]

     ["PERIODICIDADE"].ToString().Equals("0"))
        {
            this.txtDataArchive.Visible = false;

            this.dpbDataArchive.Visible = false;

            this.ddlDataPub.Visible = true;

            VerificaDataDisponivel(ds);
        }


  //Método VerificaDataDisponivel(ds)

   DataTable dtDataDisponivel = new DataTable("DataDisponivel");

        dtDataDisponivel.Columns.AddRange(new System.Data.DataColumn[] {new DataColumn("COD_DATA"), new DataColumn("DSC_DATA")});

        DataRow drData = null;
        bool flgFimCalendario = false;

        //Verify the possible dates 
        BO.Feriado feriado = new BO.Feriado();
        DataSet dsQuantArquPasta = BO.Pasta.BuscarQuantidadeArquivoPasta(this.CodPasta);

        DateTime dtul = DateTime.MinValue;
        //DateTime dtfimperio = DateTime.MinValue;

        int tipoPeriodicidade = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TipoPeriodicidade"]);

        if(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DATELASTARCHIVE"] != DBNull.Value)
        {
            dtul = (DateTime)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DATELASTARCHIVE"];
        }
```

Comment: Talvez devesses fazer questões diferentes: uma para corrigir o erro de como abrir o calendário; outra para ir buscar a próxima data no ficheiro.. No entanto aguarda um pouco porque podem sugerir respostas.